# express.js app knex.js async connection with aws secrets manager call is firing out of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, aws-secrets-manager, knex.js

I've been stuck on this for days, it feels like no matter how I structure it, the aws secret manager call ALWAYS returns after the app gets initialized. npm run start fires app.js file, this triggers knex and everything runs in order but the secrets response with the username/password seems to come back after everything's already initialized.

knex.js:

```
console.log("knex.js")
const environment = process.env.APP_ENV || 'development'
const config = require('../knexfile.js')[environment];
const knex = require('knex')(config);

module.exports = knex
```

knexfile.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path')
const pathToCert = path.resolve(__dirname, 'root.cert'); // where to save a file

console.log("knexfile.js")

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
region = 'us-east-2'
secretName = 'blah'
var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
  region: region
});
async function getConfig() {
  console.log("in get config")
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }, function (
      err,
      data
    ) {
      let secret = JSON.parse(data.SecretString);
      console.log("returning it***************" + secret.password + " " + secret.username + " " + pathToCert)
      let connectionString = `postgresql://${secret.username}:${secret.password}@some-host:1234/defaultdb?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=${pathToCert}&options=--cluster`
      resolve(connectionString)
      return

    })
  })
}
const config = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    version: 7.2,
    connection: getConfig(),
    migrations: {
      directory: './knex/migrations',
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: './knex/seeds'
    }
  }

}
console.log("exporting module")
module.exports = config
```

The console returns:

```
knex.js
knexfile.js
in get config
exporting module
Listening on: 3000
returning it***************pass username C:\project-webservice\root.cert
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Of course right after I post I figure it out :)

Right from knex documentation, I adjusted my knexfile.js based off of the following code snippet:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'postgres',
  connection: async () => {
    const { token, tokenExpiration } = await someCallToGetTheToken();
    return {
      host : 'your_host',
      port : 3306,
      user : 'your_database_user',
      password : token,
      database : 'myapp_test',
      expirationChecker: () => {
        return tokenExpiration <= Date.now();
      }
    };
  }
});
```

specifically:

```
 async () => {
    const { token, tokenExpiration } = await someCallToGetTheToken();
    return {
      host : 'your_host',
      port : 3306,
      user : 'your_database_user',
      password : token,
      database : 'myapp_test',
      expirationChecker: () => {
        return tokenExpiration <= Date.now();
      }
    };
```